# Alternative to MS SQL Server's GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

```
SELECT Category ,CASE WHEN GROUPING([Category]) = 0 THEN [Category] 
        ELSE 'Total Shown' END AS [Category]
    ,SUM([Impressions]) AS [Impressions]
    ,SUM([Clicks]) AS [Clicks]
    ,CASE WHEN SUM([Impressions]) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUM([Clicks]) / (SUM([Impressions]) * 1.0) END AS [CTR]
    ,CASE WHEN SUM([Clicks]) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUM([Cost]) / (SUM([Clicks]) * 1.0) END AS [CPClick]
    ,SUM([Cost]) AS [Spend]
    ,SUM([Transactions]) AS [Transactions]
    ,SUM([Conversions]) AS [Conversions]
    ,CASE WHEN SUM([Clicks]) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUM([Transactions]) / (SUM([Clicks]) * 1.0) END AS [Trans Rate]
    ,CASE WHEN SUM([Clicks]) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUM([Actions]) / (SUM([Clicks]) * 1.0) END AS [Action Rate]
    ,SUM([Actions]) AS [Actions]
    ,Grouping( Category ) as TotalShown

INTO #regularMetrics FROM #tmp
GROUP BY Category WITH ROLLUP 
ORDER BY TotalShown,[Impressions] desc, [Category]
```

is there any alternative of grouping in postgresql??

---

i am split into two query is it efficient?

```
SELECT [Category ] , SUM([Impressions]) AS [Impressions] ,SUM([Clicks]) AS [Clicks] ,CASE WHEN SUM([Impressions]) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUM([Clicks]) /
  (SUM([Impressions]) * 1.0) END AS [CTR] ,CASE WHEN SUM([Clicks]) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUM([Cost]) / (SUM([Clicks]) * 1.0) END AS [CPClick] ,SUM([Cost]) AS [Spend]  
  ,SUM([Transactions]) AS [Transactions]  ,SUM([Conversions]) AS [Conversions]  ,CASE WHEN SUM([Clicks]) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUM([Transactions]) / (SUM([Clicks]) * 1.0) 
  END AS "Trans Rate"  ,CASE WHEN SUM([Clicks]) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUM([Actions]) / (SUM([Clicks]) * 1.0) END AS "Action Rate"  ,SUM([Actions]) AS [Actions]  , 0 as TotalShown  
  INTO #regularMetrics  FROM #tmp GROUP BY Category   ORDER BY Category ,[Impressions] desc;

 insert into #regularmetrics(select 'Total Shown', sum(impressions), sum(clicks), CASE WHEN SUM([Impressions]) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUM([Clicks]) / (SUM([Impressions]) * 1.0) END AS [CTR], CASE WHEN SUM([Clicks]) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUM([spend]) / (SUM([Clicks]) * 1.0) END AS [CPClick], sum(spend),sum(transactions),sum(conversions), CASE WHEN SUM([Clicks]) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUM([Transactions]) / (SUM([Clicks]) * 1.0) END AS "Trans Rate"  ,CASE WHEN SUM([Clicks]) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUM([Actions]) / (SUM([Clicks]) * 1.0) END AS "Action Rate", sum(actions), 1 from #regularmetrics);
```

Comment: Please describe what that's supposed to do in Microsoft SQL Server. (Don't call it "SQL", that's a query language, not a product, despite Microsoft's irritating product naming choice). What have you already tried? What does this query do in SQL Server? Is that two separate statements, or is it a single statement that works like an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`? There's no semicolon so in PostgreSQL it'd be a single (invalid) statement, but I seem to remember MS SQL Server doesn't use semicolon statement-terminators. You're asking PostgreSQL folks; you'll need to explain the MS-SQL-serverisms.

Comment: Oh, I think the real question is "how do I do the equivalent of MS SQL Server's `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP` in PostgreSQL?" . Have I guessed correctly? If so, *explain what the query is supposed to do*. Don't expect folks learn your DBMS's details just to figure your question out. In this case it looks like it's covered by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: I'd usually down-vote this; "please convert my query for me" questions where you don't make any effort to explain the actual problem and instead just paste the query are inconsiderate at best, if not rude. In this case the underlying problem is interesting once it's guessed out of the question so I'm leaving it as-is, but **in future always try to explain the problem a little** don't just paste your query and make us guess.

Comment: Oh, I misread the first time. It's a `SELECT ... INTO` not a `SELECT` followed by an `INSERT INTO`. Sorry, thrown by the noisy and unfamiliar sytax.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you want to know how to do the equivalent of the MS SQL Server extension `WITH ROLLUP` in PostgreSQL and the rest of the query appears to be irrelevant noise.

If so, [according to MSDN, the `WITH ROLLUP` option adds subtotals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). This is not something PostgreSQL currently supports, unfortunately.

The workaround for it in PostgreSQL is to write something like:

```
WITH my_real_query AS (
    SELECT a, b
    FROM ...
    -- blah blah
)
SELECT 'line', a, b FROM my_real_query
UNION ALL
SELECT 'sum', sum(a), sum(b) FROM my_real_query;
```

depending on exactly what you want to do. This requires the inner table to be materialized and then scanned twice, so it's not exactly super-efficient. If you want to group by subsets you can do that by adding a `GROUP BY` to the second arm of the `UNION ALL` query, like:

```
WITH my_real_query AS (
    SELECT a, b
    FROM ...
    -- blah blah
)
SELECT a, b FROM my_real_query
UNION ALL
SELECT a, sum(b) FROM my_real_query GROUP BY a;
```

As for the `INSERT` part... you should generally use the SQL-standard `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` syntax. Say you wanted to insert the above into a table. You'd write:

```
INSERT INTO some_table(col1,col2)
WITH my_real_query AS (
    SELECT a, b
    FROM ...
    -- blah blah
)
SELECT a, b FROM my_real_query
UNION ALL
SELECT a, sum(b) FROM my_real_query GROUP BY a;
```

As you can see, it's really `INSERT INTO ... [QUERY]` where `[QUERY]` can be `WITH ... SELECT` etc too.

By the way, please read the [postgresql documentation on basic SQL syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax.html)  and [lexical structure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html) to learn how to write correct SQL for PostgreSQL. In general using the ANSI standard styles instead of MS SQL Server's styles will be a good starting point.

Things like `#regularMetrics` and `[Name]` are completely invalid in PostgreSQL, they're not valid syntax. Identifier quoting is done with double quotes, eg `"regularMetrics"`, `"Name"`.

Comment: @rinkesh I've updated my answer to cover the `INSERT` part too.

Comment: SQL Server's `select into ... from ... ` actually creates a new table. The Postgres equivalent would be `create table some_table as .... `